# Unresponsive select box in materialize

Tags: javascript, node.js, materialize

[image]I'm using materialize with a node backend and js front end. I'm trying to submit a form. I have the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title">Form Example</span>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" class="validate" pattern="\d{5}" title="Please enter a 5-digit zip code" />
            <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <select id="area" name="area" class="validate">
              <option value="2000">2,000 sqft</option>
              <option value="3000">3,000 sqft</option>
            </select>
            <label for="area">Area</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="submitButton">Submit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hot-container" class="mt-4">
  <!-- Handsontable grid will be displayed here -->
</div>
```

I have an error with the second field(Area) which is greyed out and half visible. It is unresponsive. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `validate` class is not applicable to the `select` element. The examples found in the [docs](https://materializeweb.com/select.html) do not illustrate one with the `validate` class. Perhaps, the validation (i.e., rejecting any null values) may have been inbuilt within the `select` element.

As for the issue with the half-visibility, can you check to see if there is a fixed `height` value for the `div.container` class? The container should ideally expand based on the number of items it carries.

UPDATE:

Looking at this again, the `select` element works if the `css` has been stripped. So, the fault lies somewhere with the `css`. If you use the next version of the `css` i.e., 1.1.0-alpha, taken from [here](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@materializecss/materialize), the `select` element now displays the dropdown field nicely. Sadly, I am not able to pinpoint what went wrong with the dropdown field with this new `css` version.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@materializecss/materialize@1.1.0-alpha/dist/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"> -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title">Form Example</span>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" class="validate" pattern="\d{5}" title="Please enter a 5-digit zip code" />
            <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-field">
            <select id="area" name="area" class="validate">
              <option value="2000">2,000 sqft</option>
              <option value="3000">3,000 sqft</option>
            </select>
            <label for="area">Area</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="submitButton">Submit</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hot-container" class="mt-4">
  <!-- Handsontable grid will be displayed here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , I removed the validate class without any effect. I don't see a reference to a fixed height in the docs

Comment: @user1592380 would it work for your project if you use the next version of the `css`, i.e., 1.1.0-alpha ?